# ajax yii jquery addclass

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I had the response on my previous post to select a specific class in a page. (using this)

I'm using Yii framework and the use of this does not work

```
<div class="ajaxlink">
        <?php           

            echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
              'Test request',         
              array($url_replace),
              array(
                   'update'=>'.loading' ,
                   'beforeSend' => 'function() {  
                       $(this).removeClass("loading");         
                       $(this).addClass("loading");
                   }',
               )
            );
        ?>
</div>
```

in short when I click the ajaxlink , I call the action view of my controller which renderPartial a view with ClistView.

I dont know how to solve the problem,  with the code above, nothing happens.

If I replace  this with Ajaxlink,   the class is added to all classes of the page.

To be clear,  when the page is rendered,  I have a list of post with related links.

```
<div class="content">

   blabla blabla

   Link
</div>
<div class="content">
   blabla blabla  2
   Link
</div>
```

when I click to the first link , I want to add a class below this link only

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: whats the problem? what do you expect and what is not happening?

Comment: @RafayZiaMir   I updted the post to give more explanation. With the code above,  there is no class added

Comment: you wan to add class below link, class is always added to html elements. Please specify to which element you want to add class?

Comment: I want to add class only below the clicked link.   Given that the class have the same name  when I use the class name content,  it add to all classes.  When I use this,  it does not add the class below the specific link.   If I use alert alert($(this).attr("class"));   I got undefined

Comment: please try lert($(this).parent().attr('class')) and do let me know, what does that produce

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.

Jquery's `next()` http://api.jquery.com/next/. Taken from JQuery

```
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
<li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
<li>list item 4</li>
<li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

$( "li.third-item" ).next().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

You could replace .css() with .addClass() and add a click()

So something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
$(this).next('.content').addClass('myClass');
});
```

Again, if I understand you correctly. This will add a class to the next `.content` div after the `<a>` is clicked.